# How to set up unit testing when developing Directus extensions?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, directus

What is a good project setup for developing Directus extensions such as hooks and custom endpoint, while using unit testing with PHPUnit?

Directus extensions live under the same codebase as the core project itself. That's a problem for having the extension code under version control. So what I have now is a symlink from `directus/public/extensions/custom/hooks` to a directory outside. In there, I have the usual `src/` and `tests/`, and I've done `composer install --dev phpunit ^8` and I PHPUnit is in place, and is loading my own classes. Now, how do I bring Directus in here, because Directus is not, AFAIK, on Composer. Maybe make a `lib/`, checkout Directus from GitHub in there, and have it included in `autoload/classmap` in composer.json?

Or would it alternatively be better to fork the whole Directus, and use a close of the whole Directus repo for extension dev? How to develop more than one extension?

Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There is not native testing for directus, the only way is to have the unit testing for php and for vue. Could be so great to have like a integration testing for the modules that uses custom api points. But the idea of directus is that all is modular so nope don't think that's gonna be around soon.